# Как выводить tooltip при вводе запрещенных символов?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void emailBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {


        if(!Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != 8 && !Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) == true)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar < 33 &&  e.KeyChar > 47) // При вводе допустим этих символов tooltip не вылазит

        {
            toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
            toolTip1.Show("Забыли ввести", this.emailBox, 1000);
        }


    }
```

В этом куске кода пытался сделать аналогичный hint, но он не выводится.

```
       else if (e.KeyChar < 33 &&  e.KeyChar > 47) // При вводе допустим этих символов tooltip не вылазит
        {
            toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
            toolTip1.Show("Ввод запрещенных символов", emailBox);
        }
```

[Вот пример hint'a который хочу реализовать](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeDPN.png)

Comment: это называется валидация, в другом ответе была ссылка на этот пример. Email проверяется специальным регулярным выражением
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/2608/c-validating-textbox-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как решил этот вопрос

```
private void emailBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string pattern = @"^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
            @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,17}))$";


            if (Regex.IsMatch(emailBox.Text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                incorrinput.Clear(); // incorrinput - это компонент errorprovider
                email = true; // Это собственная проверка на переход в другую форму
            }
            else
            {
                incorrinput.SetError(emailBox, "Data was entered incorrectly or invalid characters were used");
                email = false; // Это собственная проверка на переход в другую форму
            }
    }
```